# How to aggregate grouping with filtered array and filtered sum?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get my head around this aggregation framework, and I'm kind of stuck, I would love some help.

So I have a collection of events, that simplified and already filtered look something similar to this:

```
{ creation: 54233, eventName: "elapsedTime", userId: 1, url: "/thing/53e245ca", data: { number: 5 } },
{ creation: 64033, eventName: "elapsedTime", userId: 1, url: "/thing/53e245ca", data: { number: 3 } },
{ creation: 50298, eventName: "elapsedTime", userId: 1, url: "/thing/53e245ca", data: { number: 2 } },
{ creation: 74220, eventName: "toggle",      userId: 1, url: "/thing/53e245ca", data: { status: true } },
{ creation: 84233, eventName: "elapsedTime", userId: 2, url: "/thing/190345a9", data: { number: 8 } },
{ creation: 59511, eventName: "elapsedTime", userId: 2, url: "/thing/190345a9", data: { number: 10 } },
{ creation: 14236, eventName: "toggle",      userId: 2, url: "/thing/190345a9", data: { status: false } },
{ creation: 80637, eventName: "toggle",      userId: 2, url: "/thing/cc2b8b91", data: { status: true } },
{ creation: 99239, eventName: "toggle",      userId: 2, url: "/thing/cc2b8b91", data: { status: false } }
```

And I want them to be aggregated like this:

```
{
    userId: 1,
    toggles: [
        { creation: 74220, url: "/thing/53e245ca", data: { status: true } }
    ],
    elapsedSum: 10
},
{
    userId: 2,
    toggles: [
        { creation: 14236, url: "/thing/190345a9", data: { status: false } },
        { creation: 80637, url: "/thing/cc2b8b91", data: { status: true } },
        { creation: 99239, url: "/thing/cc2b8b91", data: { status: false } },
    ],
    elapsedSum: 18
}
```

So I basically want to group by user, have the sum of all `elapsedTime` for each user, and have an array of all the `toggle` events for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('heya').aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$userId",
      "toogles": {
        "$addToSet": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$eventName",
                "toggle"
              ]
            },
            "then": {
              "creation": "$creation",
              "url": "$url",
              "data": "$data"
            },
            "else": null
          }
        }
      },
      "elapsedSum": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$eventName",
                "elapsedTime"
              ]
            },
            "then": "$data.number",
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You may replace null from the array or unwind it to get the required result

Comment: Wow I don't know how I didn't think of that. It was way simpler than I thought. Thank you very much!